# SQL - Comparing two tables with Minus - Include/Exclude temp field

Tags: sql

After carefully reading a lot of topics about comparing tables and using the minus function I'm posting this.

I've got my comparison between two tables running.

```
Select Column1,Column2.. from table 1
minus Column1,Column2.. from table 2
union all
Column1,Column2.. from table 2
Select Column1,Column2.. from table 1
order by column1
```

Now this gives me a list of duplicate or single values that are different in each table. This is fine. However I do not have an indicator telling me in which table the (faulty) rows are. 
I tried adding a temporary column giving it an A and B field. This results in a full export of the table because this obviously gets taken in with the minus function.

Is there a way that I can tag the rows telling me what table they are in without adding a permanent column in the table,because this is not an option.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: It seems complicated but actually isn't, if we get sample and output data.

Comment: Please do not tag all RDBMS. Please tag only RDBMS which you are using. If this is general sql question please tag just sql.

Comment: Hi Suraz, what would you need?

Columns would contain an ID and an Item caption for example. Any typo or different value would give me an output of both rows/ID's and letting me compare them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example query you provided isn't syntactically correct and has errors when running. But, based on the description of what you tried, I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

You were on the right track with adding a temporary column that provides an indicator of which table is the source of the row. The value of the temporary column should be the same for the queries before the `UNION ALL` and a different value for the queries after.

Here's an updated version of your example query. You can try it out at <kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ea6b8/8)</kbd>

```
(
  SELECT 'FromTable1', COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE1
  EXCEPT
  SELECT 'FromTable1', COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE2
)
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 'FromTable2', COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE2
  EXCEPT
  SELECT 'FromTable2', COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM TABLE1
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Adam. this is exactly what I needed. Tested it and works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I would phrase this as a union of left joins:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, 'table1' AS label
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t2.col1 IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.col1, t2.col2, 'table2'
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t1.col1 IS NULL
```

The `label` column is computed during the `UNION` and serves to label the origin table for each record (i.e. set of values) which are unique to that particular table.  Note that you can extend what I have given above by adding the necessary number of columns to fill both tables.

This is a general solution which should work across most RDBMS, and doesn't rely on any set difference operators.

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Thank you for replying Tim. Unfortunatly it gives me an error.
 "column ambiguously defined"

Comment: @gandalf Sorry, I had a typo in the column aliases.  I have updated along with a Fiddle demo you can try.

Comment: +1 for not relying on a set difference operator such as `MINUS` or `EXCEPT` (depending on RMDBS), since not all databases support that.